# Codeigniter Autoloading Entire Folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter and have been reading about the autoloader functions.  So for example in application/config/autoload.php I can add file names to the assigned array to have it autoload. But that is not what I want.  You only have an option to add your custom files to these folders below

| 1. Packages
| 2. Libraries
| 3. Drivers
| 4. Helper files
| 5. Custom config files
| 6. Language files
| 7. Models

In my scenario, I'd like to add another folder called "objects" at the same level as the folders listed above.  So basically I would add 8. Objects to the list of available autoload paths.

But the problem with this file is that you must specify the filenames of the files you want to be autoloaded in that directory. What I'd like to do is autoload the entire directory of "objects".  I've been searching for the right spot for hours but feel like im going in circles in the code.

So my ultimate questions are...
1. Where can I add a new autoload path like controllers?
2. How can I load everything within that new folder?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Current version of CodeIgniter 3? Are your "objects" just classes? If so, why separate them? Anyways, you'd just extend /system/core/Loader.php with an /application/core/MY_Loader.php, and add the functionality you desire.

Comment: my objects are classes with properties and database info.  I use reflection to get the properties of each object so I can have 1 extendable controller class. I do this so i can add objects at any time without writing any additional code.  under my_loader.php, how can I load all files in that folder without listing out each file name?  I need it to work the the controllers folder

Comment: You'll probably want to initiate some work on that MY_Loader project, and then ask questions that are specific to it. Regardless of why you think it's a good idea, it's just not something that I'm interested in spending time coding up. I don't mind helping when you get stuck, but you're going to have to start the work.

Comment: thanks.  I'll keep looking